# How to get gif animation URL associated with a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When post is displayed in the feed, Facebook displays a "safe" version of it, usually rendered as .mp4 . How can I get it using Graph API when retrieving post?

/me/posts fields=message,video does not work (unknown field video).
fields=picture,full_picture both retrieve static thubmnail.

Comment: you can fetch the attachments of the post (fields=attachments), but they link to a video id on Facebook, so obviously the attached gif is internally a linked mp4 video. I found no way to get the gif again, but perhaps you have some other ideas ... check the video :)

Comment: @Norbert, I wonder why did you post a perfectly valid answer as a comment? :)
BTW, do you by any chance know how do I know if attachment was a gif (e.g. if I need to loop it)

Comment: It's not that perfect, because I have no idea how you can determine that a video was a gif before uploading to Facebook.